# Flutter/RiverPod - can't be assigned to the parameter type 'AlwaysAliveProviderListenable<Journey?>'

Tags: flutter, riverpod

In my Flutter/RiverPod app I am trying to connect three distinct providers, as shown below, but I' getting an error...

```
The argument type 'FutureProvider<Journey?>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'AlwaysAliveProviderListenable<Journey?>'.
```

The code...

```
final journeyFilterProvider = StateProvider<String?>( (ref) {
  return null;
});

// ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

final findJourneyProvider = FutureProvider<Journey?>((ref) async {
  String? aJourneyId = ref.watch(journeyFilterProvider);
  if (aJourneyId == null) {
    return null;
  } else {
    Journey? aJourney = await ref.watch(journeyServiceProvider).findById(aJourneyId);
    if (aJourney == null) {
      return null;
    } else {
      if (ref.watch(routeServiceProvider).hasCachedRoute(aJourney.routeId,aJourney.routeStartLocation) == false) {
        await ref.watch(routeServiceProvider).loadRoute(aJourney.routeId, aJourney.routeStartLocation);
        aJourney.lengthInKm = RouteDefinitionUtil.routeDistance(aJourney.routeId);
        // if (aJourney.collectorsConnected.count > 0) {
        //   await refreshCollectors();
        // }
      }
    }
    return aJourney;
  }
});

// ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

final journeyCrudProvider = StateNotifierProvider<JourneyCrudNotifier,JourneyModel>( (ref) {
  Journey? aJourney = ref.watch(findJourneyProvider);  <=== ERROR REPORTED HERE!!
  JourneyModel aModel = JourneyModel();
  aModel.journey = aJourney;
  return JourneyCrudNotifier(
      ref.watch(journeyServiceProvider),
      ref.watch(latestPositionServiceProvider),
      ref.watch(notificationServiceProvider),
      ref.watch(fitbitTravelServiceProvider),
      ref.watch(routeServiceProvider),
      ref.watch(groupServiceProvider),
      aModel);
});

// ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest option is to use `valueOrNull`:

```
Journey? aJourney = ref.watch(findJourneyProvider).valueOrNull;
```

If you do not want to return previous value during loading/error states, consider using `asData`:

```
Journey? aJourney = ref.watch(findJourneyProvider).asData?.valueOrNull;
```

Answer (score 0):

`ref.watch` on an async provider returns a value that is wrapped in the appropriate `AsyncValue` subclass (Data, Error, Loading).  You need to take the value from `ref.watch` and use the various `AsyncValue` methods, like `.when`.

Answer (score 0):

The Problem is we cannot able to assign the  AsyncValue of Journey  to Normal  Value of Journey ,
You need to change

```
 instead of 

 Journey? aJourney = ref.watch(findJourneyProvider);

 you need to assign Either 

 final aJourney = ref.watch(findJourneyProvider);

                or 

 AsyncValue<Journey?> aJourney = ref.watch(findJourneyProvider);
```